# Convert binary contents in BLOB field in the database to files mySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, blob

I have got to retrieve binary in LONGBLOB field from the db. This field is storing all sorts of file formats such as txt, doc, xdoc, pdf, etc. I basically need to be able to convert the binary format into their actual file formats in order to allow my user to download these files.

Has anyone got any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, it would be best have another field to store the format.  You can do this by copying the extension (ie, everything after the last "." in the file name).  The best way would probably be to get the file's mime type: [see this for example](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html).

You can then store the mime type in a field in the database.  This will almost always work, whereas the extension of a file can be misleading (or vague).

Answer (score 1):

Adding a field file_format indicating the file format of the file stored in LONGBLOB, then you  are able to convert the binary according to the associated file format.

or, reserve the first several bytes for file format, after that is the actual content of file.

Answer (score 1):

I think u should have another field to save the document type and tell which type should be converted. Use I/O InputStream to read/write file.

What I recommend is upload the client files to somewhere, save the path that's link to these file into db. That should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

as others have suggested. create another column(FILETYPE_COL_NAME) in database which will tell you which type of file is stored in `BOLB`(BLOB_COL_NAME) field and then you extend the below code in `try/catch` block

```
String fileType = rs.getString("FILETYPE_COL_NAME"); 

DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("filepath."+fileType )));

ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("Select * from tablename");

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(rs.getBinaryStream("BLOB_COL_NAME"));

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

int byteread = 0;

while((byteread = bis.read(buffer)) != -1){
        dos.write(buffer, 0, byteread);
}

dos.flush();
dos.close();
bis.close();
```